# radiobuttonlist selected value javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

just want to ask, is there an equivalent selectedvalue in this code? like

`<%=radiobuttonlistID.ClientID.SelectedValue="1"%>`?

I'm trying to find an equivalent code to this like

`radiobuttonlistID.SelectedValue = "1";` I'm asking is there an extension in ClientID equivalent to selectedvalue?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetRadioButtonSelectedValue() {
        var AspRadio = document.getElementById('<%= Aspradiobuttonlist.ClientID %>');
        var AspRadio_ListItem = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < AspRadio_ListItem.length; i++) {

            if (AspRadio_ListItem[i].checked) {
                var lblAspradiobuttonValue = document.getElementById('<%= lblAspradiobuttonValue.ClientID %>');

                lblAspradiobuttonValue.innerHTML = '<b>Selected Value:</b> ' + AspRadio_ListItem[i].value + '<br/>';
                lblAspradiobuttonValue.innerHTML += '<b>Selected Text:</b> ' + AspRadio_ListItem[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].innerHTML;
            } //end if

        } // end for

    } //end function
</script>
```

Refer this :http://codedisplay.com/javascript-how-to-get-read-asp-radio-button-list-selected-value-selected-text-onclick-event-c-vb-net/

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope to understand what you need...
Suppose you have this html code:

```
<form id="radiolist">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male" >Male
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female">Female
</form>
```

this javascript does what you want

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("male").checked = true;
</script>
```

Bye...